# How can I solve UnicodeDecodeError in Django?

Tags: python, django, encoding

I am getting this error in Django:

```
 UnicodeDecodeError at /category/list/

 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf5 in position 7: invalid start byte

 Request Method:    GET
 Request URL: ...
 Django Version:    1.3.1
 Exception Type:    UnicodeDecodeError
 Exception Value:   

 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf5 in position 7: invalid start byte

 Exception Location:                       /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py in iterencode, line 264
 ...
```

I should save Turkish characters in the database. How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code solved my problem. Thank you.

```
if isinstance(encObject, unicode):
                           myStr = encObject.encode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 4):

A start-byte of 0xf5 would indicate the start of a 4-character UTF-8 encoding. One strong possibility is that the input isn't UTF-8 at all but [ISO-8859-9](http://www.unicodetools.com/unicode/codepages.php?codepage=iso-8859-9), the Turkish ISO encoding. On that codepage 0xf5 is a lowercase o with tilde or `õ`.

Comment: Yes it is an ö. So I should be careful on saving the strings, or getting the strings from the DB? Also I am using django-trans for translations. Can it be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/f5/index.htm

it is an o with a tilde

try

```
some_string.decode('latin1','replace')
```