# Why Django doesn't run on local server and How to fix it?

Tags: django

When I try to run the local server of Django with the aid of command line, I get the following results:

[image: print screen with results, click here]

As far I understand, there are several errors. What is the problem and how I can fix it?

(Django version-1.7.3, Python -3.4, OC -Windows7)

Comment: Not sure how you went about to get that output from the command line. But it would probably help if you posted your traceback.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746405/how-can-i-solve-unicodedecodeerror-in-django

Comment: @dan-klasson I did it in according to the basic manual: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/ After executing python manage.py migrate, I typed: d:\djaproject\mysite>python manage.py runserver. And It's going wrong (as for me).

Comment: What part of the tutorial did you encounter that? Did you try to insert values into the database? If so, did you create your db as unicode?

Comment: So you did `startproject`, then `migrate` and then `runserver` and you got that?

Comment: @dan-klasson All procedure (I've made another project): 1. Create a new project: d:\djaproject> django-admin startproject newsite 2.In DIR: d\djaproject\newsite  ==> manage.py migrate (all settings by default: base SQ Lite, UTF-8 by default also) ==> result: Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: sessions, admin, contenttypes, auth
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK etc..
       ==> Next: d:\djaproject\newsite> python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks... (and I have the same result as on printscreen)